# Method inside the method

Tags: java

I written the below code

```
List<UserDetails> getUserList(String Json){         
    try {                   
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Json);
        int myname = jsonObject.getInt("itemsPerPage");
        System.out.println(myname);                         

        JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("list"); 
        System.out.println(jsonarray.length());

        if(null != jsonarray && jsonarray.length() == 25){
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            URL= someurl;               
            checkValue="USERDETAILS";
            startIndex += 25; 
            String jsonResult = restClient.postJiveUsersData(URL,restUserName,restPassword);
            if(null != jsonResult) {
                getUserList(jsonResult);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("User List size::" +userDetailsList.size());
        return userDetailsList;
```

---

After executing the above the "User List size" is printing more than once. May I know reason and is there any way to avoid tomultiple time to print it.

Thanking for helping in advance.

Regards
Narasimha Reddy P

Comment: could you provide the full source code?

Comment: Might be you are calling getUserList in a loop?

Comment: if(null != jsonResult) {
                `getUserList(jsonResult);`
            }

Answer (score 3):

It is printing more than once because your `getUserList` method is calling itself, so `System.out.println("User List size::" +userDetailsList.size());` is executed multiple times.